# Need a animation to move slowly a single line text in android

Tags: android

I need an animation so that a very large text view keeps moving from left to right slowly.
I have done this using slide_in and slide_out but it doesn't solve the purpose. Please help.

EDIT:
I was able to get the scrolling but i am getting it in multiple lines at a time.i.e, 3 texts in 3 lines,where as I need them in a single line please help.

Comment: share more details about your issue.What exactly do you want.your information is unsufficient to give a perfect solution.

Comment: I have 3 texts and right now I am dynamically changing them using slid_in and slide_out. I want to make them into a single large text and slowly slide continuously from left to right some thing like this http://www.gulte.com/index.php

Answer (score 5):

create this xml in anim folder
**translate.xml**

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromXDelta="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-500" />
```

call this animation in your activity, and adjust delta and duration as you need.

```
textView.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.translate));
```

OR

if you want vertical scrolling
try this link https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/blob/master/ignition-core/ignition-core-lib/src/com/github/ignition/core/widgets/ScrollingTextView.java

Create the java file in your project and call the custom view in your layout.

```
<com.example.test.ScrollingTextView
        android:id="@+id/scrollingTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="ScrollingTextView" />
```

OR

If you just want the text inside a textview to scroll itself

```
<TextView
    android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: It works but as i said earlier i have 3 texts I added them in the same string with space, now the problem is all three of them are coming at the same time.

Comment: https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition/blob/master/ignition-core/ignition-core-lib/src/com/github/ignition/core/widgets/ScrollingTextView.java

Comment: try this custom view. This will automatically scroll your content

Comment: Create this java file in your project.

Comment: where do i call the custum view and why is this xml needed? I am sorry i am new to android.

Comment: place this xml instead of your textview. And com.example.test is my package name. Change that to your package name.

Comment: if your are using eclipse, open your layout and click on custom and library views. press refresh. drag and drop this custom view. that will be enough.

Comment: What is ScrollingTextView? It is not recognizable ? I have added this in place of TextView now how to call this ScrollingTextView ?

Comment: havent u copied the java class from  the link?

Comment: But this is not what i needed i need a horizontal linear scroller this is scrolling vertical and the text is same as before.

Comment: @brk8055 - I think perhaps you should have put more details into your original question. How are we supposed to magically know exactly what you need without your giving us the details in advanced. Take a look [here on how to formulate a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Base your code in this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvId);
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,tv.getWidth()+20, 0, 0);
animate.setDuration(1000);
tv.startAnimation(animate);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I think it's simple

Comment: I think it works but as i said earlier i have 3 texts I added them in the same string with space, now the problem is all three of them are coming at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This can reasonably be achieved in a single line statement in API 12 and above. Below is an example where `v` is the view you wish to animate;

```
v.animate()
    .translationXBy(-1000)
    .start();
```

This will slide the `View` in question off to the left by 1000px. To slide the view back to the right we can simply do the following.

```
v.animate()
    .translationXBy(1000)
    .start();
```

If the above is too fast you can set the amount of time over which it occurs, and therefore set the speed by adding a call to `.setDuration(timeInMs)` into the chain. For example, if we wanted it to take 5 seconds to move to the right by 1000 pixels we could do;

```
v.animate()
    .translationXBy(1000)
    .setDuration(5000)
    .start();
```

If your doing more than one animation at a time and you want them to occur one after the other you could add `setStartDelay(timeInMs)` into the chain to make sure one animation comes after the other. For example, using three different views we could do the following;

```
v.animate()
    .translationXBy(1000)
    .setDuration(5000)
    .start();
v2.animate()
    .translationXBy(1000)
    .setStartDelay(5000)
    .setDuration(5000)
    .start();
v3.animate()
    .translationXBy(1000)
    .setStartDelay(10000)
    .setDuration(5000)
    .start();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works but as i said earlier i have 3 texts I added them in the same string with space, now the problem is all three of them are coming at the same time.And my minimum api is 11.

Comment: If you want the three lines to move independently of each other, then your going to need all three lines separated into different views.

Comment: Okay let us say i have 3 text views say a,b,c how am i going to implement it?

Comment: Well, using the method in my answer you could just call `setStartDelay(timeInMs)` on the animation before calling start to make sure some views are animated later than others. I'll update that into my answer.

Comment: it hides the image i dont want to hide?